# Regex to match numbers, commas, dots, spaces in a given string

Tags: regex

I'm writing a regex to match any numbers, commas, dots, except when they are at the end of the number.

Here is an example of what I have so far:

```
/([0-9]+[., ]*)+/
```

This is pretty good already because it is matching what I want. The only issue is that it's matching ' ' or ',' '.' at the end of the expression too.

Let's say I have this string:

```
The cost of the food was 1 999,49 € without drinks.
```

I want to match the `1 999,49` string. Right now my regexp is matching `1 999,49` . The same should happen if the format of the price is different like:

```
1,999.49 $ => 1,999.49 (with no whitespace or anything in the end)
```

How can I do this with regular expressions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use a pattern to first match the digits and optionally match either a space, comma or dot followed by 1+ digit so that the dot comma or space can not be at the end.

```
\d+(?:[,. ]\d+)*
```

- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[,. ]\d+` Match either a space `,` or `.` and 1+ digits
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iMPrU4/1)

A bit more precise match could be

```
\b\d{1,3}(?:[,. ]\d{3})*(?:[.,]\d{2})?\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yi6Hy9/1)

Comment: Thank you the first one seems to be working pretty great. What would I have to do if I want to allow `.` to be at the end but don't want commas or whitespaces? Does this look ok? `\d+(?:[, ]\d+)*([.])*`

Comment: @Radical_Activity Then you could consider a pattern like `\b\d{1,3}(?:[,. ]\d{3})*(?:\.\d{2})?\b`

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to do so with the first formula? `\d+(?:[,. ]\d+)*`

Comment: @Radical_Activity To match only digits or a part with a comma and a dot at the end `\d+(?:(?:[, ]\d+)+(?:\.\d+))?` https://regex101.com/r/vTbjLu/1